# "We help consumers pay less" vs. "Helping consumers paying less"

Tags: word-choice, business-language

Since English is not my native language I can not decide which one of the following two sentences is better.

1. We help companies sell more and consumers pay less.
2. Helping companies sell more and consumers paying less.

Answer (score 1):

The first is a sentence and is fine.

The second is a phrase but would be better written as either of

- Helping companies sell more and consumers pay less
- Helping companies sell more with consumers paying less

depending on who you are helping.

There is no require for a corporate slogan to be a sentence.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And especially for the tip about slogan.  In this case everyone is helped. Which of your two example is the one that shows this ?

Comment: The former.  You could expand it to *Helping companies to sell more and consumers to pay less*

Answer (score 1):

At the least, sentence 2 should read Helping companies sell more and consumers pay less.

And it depends on how you are planning to use it. If this is a slogan for something I would use option 2. But then the logo/name of who is helping needs to be very visible for it to have an effect.

As an explanatory/informational sentence, you can use option 1.

Comment: I'd say 1 makes a better slogan -- 2 is more passive.